# Add class to element inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, iterable

I have an item list generated with `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items"> 
  <div>
     <span>item.description<span>
     <span>item.price</span>
     <button (click)="removeItem(item.id)"> x <button>
  </div>
  ...
```

The `removeItem` functions makes a `DELETE` request to an API endpoint and deletes the item successfully, but the item remains in the view unless I refresh the page.

What I want is to apply a class to set `display:none` to the deleted item, I have used this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" [class.dismissed]="itemRemoved">
```

In the `.ts` file the `itemRemoved` is initialized like this:

```
itemRemoved: boolean = false;
```

And in the function `removeItem` is set to `true` when the API call is successful:

```
this.http.delete(url)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log("Item removed");
      this.itemRemoved = true;
    },
```

But the class is applied to all the items.

How can I apply the class just to the item that I'm removing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the item is removed from the `items` array, it wll be removed from the DOM. There should be no need to use `display: none`

Comment: as mentioned by @user184994 , you can modify your `removeItem` method to search for the `item` with the passed id and then remove it(with `splice` or any other method) from the `items` array

Comment: @roymckrank can you show your component code so that i could assist you

Answer (score 0):

`itemRemoved` is a class-wide variable.  When you set it to true, its true for everyone.  One way you can do it is to have an array of ids that you've removed, and pass a function to the class input that checks to see if the ID is in said array.

(untested, but gist):

```
export class MyComponent {
  removedItems: any[] = [];

  removeItem(item) {
    this.http.delete(url)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("Item removed");
        this.removedItems.push(item);
      })
  }

  isRemoved(item) {
    return this.removedItems.find(i => item.id === i.id);
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="removeItem(item)" [class.dismissed]="isRemoved(item)">x</div>
```

#### Edit:

Or as Juan mentioned in the comments, remove the item from the array you're iterating over.  Depends on how `items` is being populated.

Comment: `items` is an object, I will try your solution!

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a `isRemoved` property to your `item` so we could distinguish which item was removed. So you need to pass the whole item on the method function then assign the `isRemoved` property to the `item`. in the the you then detect with an if statement if the `item` is removed.

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div *ngIf="!item.isRemoved">
     <span>item.description</span>
     <span>item.price</span>
     <button (click)="removeItem(item)"> x </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in your TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [
    {
      description: 'sample',
      price: 10
    }
  ];

  public removeItem(item) {
    item.isRemoved = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a class to delete that item from the view. The simplest way to do this is remove the item from the array you are iterating. In your example:

```
  removeItem(item) {
    this.http.delete(url)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log("Item removed");
        let index = this.items.indexOf(item);
        this.items.splice(index,1);
      })
  }
```

I Hope be helpfull.